# How to prevent the reset of form inputs when reloading a page in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm building a web application which might (occasionally) reload the page in order to update some informations that are displayed on the page using Expression Language. In Firefox everything works fine, but in Chrome every time the page is reloaded all the content from the input fields is lost and the form is reset to blank. That is too annoying for the user, who has to type once again all the content that's gone lost. Is there any way to replicate in Chrome the same behaviour as Firefox with plain HTML, or is it necessary to use some Javascript? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the input fields located inside a `<form>` tag ?

Comment: Yes they are. I'm using Spring Form Tags, if that can make any difference (but I guess it doesn't).

Comment: Instead of reloading the page, submit the form, so you can write the submitted values into <input value="">

Comment: You mean using JS to submit the form to a different controller (not the controller normally handling the form submission) which would just spit back the form page view updated? Sounds interesting. Thanks a lot! I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say this is your code:

```
<form id="formId" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenAction" name="hiddenAction" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="" />
</form>
```

If you are using a form, simply submit the form using `JavaScript`instead of refreshing the page.

If you can see that I added a `hidden input` at the beginning of the form. Used to track the submission action

```
$("#formId #hiddenAction").val("refreshed") ;
$("#formId").submit() ;
```

And then in your `php` at the beginning of the page put the following:

```
<?php
    $firstName = "" ;
    if (isset($_POST["hiddenAction"]) && $_POST["hiddenAction"] == "refreshed") { //When the hidden action is set to "refreshed" then we know that this is coming from refreshing the page
        $firstName = isset($_POST["firstName"]) ? $_POST["firstName"] : "" ; //Of course you have to escape the string and strip it from any pure html tags
    }
?>
```

And in your `<html>` code, change all your input tags respectively with their related values to match the below:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName ?>" />
```

Comment: I had to make some adaptations since I'm using Spring MVC rather than PHP, but your answer solved my problem, so I accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use some little Javascript ..

Like saving Data in Cookie / Local Storage / etc...